# If I incompletely populate my array of characters then what would be the values stored in the addresses which are empty?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

My task is to append a "." (dot) after the last element of an array of characters and my strategy is to add the dot as soon as I encounter a '\0' in my search.But even if the array has elements lesser than the space allocated to it, the dot is appended at the last location.
For example if I have allocated an array of size 10 and I input only 5 characters, then also the dot is appended to the array in the 10th place.How can I get around with this ?
Following is the C code that I have written :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char dot = '.';
    char string_input[10];
    fgets (string_input, sizeof(string_input), stdin);
    int s = sizeof(string_input);
    for(i=0;i<=s;++i)
    {
        if (string_input[i]!= '\0')
    {
        continue;
        }
            else
            {
                string_input[i]=dot;
                printf("Hello, %s\n", string_input);
        break;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i<=s` is an off-by-one-error; should be `i<s`.

Comment: `string_input[i]=dot;` overwrites the `\0` terminator. Now `string_input` is not a string anymore and passing it to `printf` `%s` is an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To append dots up to the end of the character array try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char dot = '.';
    char string_input[10];
    const size_t N = sizeof( string_input );

    fgets( string_input, N, stdin );

    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i < N - 1 && string_input[i] != '\n' && string_input[i] != '\0' ) ++i;

    while ( i < N - 1 ) string_input[i++] = dot;
    string_input[i] = '\0';

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", string_input );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that function `fgets` also reads the new line character that corresponds to the pressed key Enter provided that it has enough space to store it.

If to enter for example

```
abcd
```

then output will be

```
"abcd....."
```

If you want to add only one dot to the end of the string then you can write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char dot = '.';
    char string_input[10];
    const size_t N = sizeof( string_input );

    fgets( string_input, N, stdin );

    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i < N - 1 && string_input[i] != '\n' && string_input[i] != '\0' ) ++i;

    if ( i < N - 1 ) string_input[i++] = dot;
    string_input[i] = '\0';

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", string_input );

    return 0;
}
```

Here the output will be

```
"abcd."
```

Comment: @melpomene Are you sure?:)

Comment: Yes, but you can't tell because your program also produces no output.

Comment: @melpomene  Does fgets produce input?

Comment: What does it mean to "produce input"?

Comment: @melpomene Oh you mean output. No proble.:)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using

```
int s = sizeof(string_input);
```

which gives the amount on memory the string takes - in this case 10 bytes, regardless of its content.

Note also that this

```
for(i=0;i<=s;++i)
```

is incorrect since you must not attempt to index `string_input[10]`, that index is out of range.

I suggest you use `strlen()` which will give the string length actually used, *including the `newline` character* appended by `fgets()`. Then overwrite the `newline` like this

```
for(i=0;i<s;++i)
{
    if (string_input[i] == '\n')
        {
            string_input[i]=dot;
            printf("Hello, %s\n", string_input);
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: But the loop stops at the first `'\0'`, which is equivalent to using `strlen`.

Comment: @melpomene yes that's true but OP result is ignoring the `newline` that `fgets()` places at the end of the string. If he overwrites that intead of the string terminator, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are several fundamental issues with your code, apart from the off-by-one error pointed out by melpomene. First, if you want to append some character after a string *in-place*, then you should make room for it ahead of time.  So instead of

```
fgets (string_input, sizeof(string_input), stdin);
```

You should write

```
fgets (string_input, sizeof(string_input)-1, stdin);
```

Then you also need to terminate your string with `'\0'` after overwriting it with dot. So instead of saying

```
string_input[i]=dot;
```

You should say

```
string_input[i]=dot;
string_input[i+1]='\0';
```

In terms of coding style, you need to pay attention to

- correct indentation
- avoiding some subtle but silly things, like `if ( A!=B ) { continue; } else {...}` which is simply `if (A==B) {...}`; also you can easily avoid invoking `sizeof` twice by swapping the two statements.

I'm pointing those out as I see you're probably learning the language.